# PDA state diagram with an inifinite languge but with no looping states

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

For class I'm supposed to create a PDA state diagram that is capable of generating an infinite language with no state q such that q is reachable from the start state, there is no cycle within the diagram that starts at q and ends at q, and there is not path from q to and end state.

Essentially, I'm trying to prove that a PDA does not need looping states to create an infinite language but I do not know the first place to start. I know that a PDA can make use of lambda transitions which could possibly be to my benefit, and I know that there can be multiple paths resulting from the same transition but I cannot wrap my head around an infinite number of possibilities without any sort of loop. I suppose I'm not looking for a definitive answer, more so something to get me pointing in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: "no state q such that q is reachable from the start state, there is no cycle within the diagram that starts at q and ends at q, and there is not path from q to and end state" seems to mean: "Every reachable state is _either_ in a cycle, _or_ can reach the end state (or both)". Is that the intended conditition? (If so, it is easy to enforce for any automaton: Just identify all states that _cannot_ reach the end, and replace all their transition with a self-loop for each symbol in the alphabet. This clearly doesn't change the accepted language).

Comment: It turns out, it was a trick question. I had thought the question was asking to create a state diagram where there were no loops AND the language was infinite. Instead it was to show that a PDA state diagram can have looping states whose conditions for reaching the accept state are impossible (i.e.  popping a character that is not in the language) but are still connected to the final state.